# Convert object dtype column to float or int

Tags: python, dtype

I'm trying to cluster some data, but when i`m trying to run k-means i get the error: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Point'

[image]

I think I need to change the dtype

My pandas df gives me the following dtypes:

```
Trajectory ID                                  object
Ordinal of the point within the trajectory    float64
Timestamp                                      object
Latitude                                      float64
Longitude                                     float64
dtype: object
```

I need to convert objects to float or to int the to put into k-means clustering algorithm

Answer (score 2):

> There is a helper class in scikit-learn which implements this nicely,
>   it's called sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder

Use this class's `fit_transform` function to encode the string and `inverse_transform` to get back original